# How to avoid parsing of json object in ISuperObject-typed field

Tags: json, delphi, marshalling, xsuperobject

Long time ago we decided to use `XSuperObject` library for marshalling objects into json for transition between two parts of system. One of fields represents as `ISuperObject` on server side and as various object on client side.

The idea is that I send objects to server and then it returns one of this back without any changes. For example I send this:

```
[
  {
    "NAME": "Today",
    "VALUE": {"loginIndex": 0,"shipmentDate": "2023-09-08","shipmentAddressId": "","paymentMethodId": "","shipmentMethodId": "","shipmentOfficeId": ""},
    "IS_DEFAULT": false,
    "ID": 0,
    "WH_ID": 0
  },
  {
    "NAME": "Monday",
    "VALUE": {"loginIndex": 0,"shipmentDate": "2023-09-11","shipmentAddressId": "","paymentMethodId": "","shipmentMethodId": "","shipmentOfficeId": ""},
    "IS_DEFAULT": false,
    "ID": 0,
    "WH_ID": 0
  },
  {
    "NAME": "Tuesday",
    "VALUE": {"loginIndex": 0,"shipmentDate": "2023-09-12","shipmentAddressId": "","paymentMethodId": "","shipmentMethodId": "","shipmentOfficeId": ""},
    "IS_DEFAULT": false,
    "ID": 0,
    "WH_ID": 0
  }
]
```

and translate into object with this structure:

```pascal
TMySelectedItem = record
  NAME:String;
  VALUE:ISuperObject;
  IS_DEFAULT:Boolean;
  ID:Integer;
  WH_ID:Integer;
end
```

When I translate JSON to object using `TSuperRecord<TMySelectedItem>.FromJSON(Resp.Data[i])`, extract VALUE field and translate it into string using `VALUE.AsJSON`, I expect this:

```
{"loginIndex": 0,"shipmentDate": "2023-09-08","shipmentAddressId": "","paymentMethodId": "","shipmentMethodId": "","shipmentOfficeId": ""}
```

but instead, server returns me this:

```
{"loginIndex": 0,"shipmentDate": "2023-09-07Z","shipmentAddressId": "","paymentMethodId": "","shipmentMethodId": "","shipmentOfficeId": ""}
```

As you can see, it not only recognize field `shipmentDate` as date, as I suppose, it also changes timezone despite lack of time value in this string and especially I didn't tell it, that this field is a date. Can I mark field, typed ISuperObject to translate into output json as is, without any changes?

Comment: Why isn't `TMySelectedItem.VALUE` defined as a `record` on its own? What **exactly** is your code to "_extract_" and "_translate_" what has already been parsed as JSON back into a `String`? Edit your question, make it reproducible.

Comment: Server side can't know structure of `TMySelectedItem.VALUE`. Every client use his own structure of this field: object, array or just one scalar value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you use ([XSuperObject](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject)) has built-in recognition of date, time and date-time values from JSON string values when reading JSON. This is enabled by default.

Some of the APIs in the library gives you control over this behavior - `TSuperObject.Create(JSON: String = '{}'; const CheckDate: Boolean = True)`, but this is not the case of `TSuperRecord<T>.FromJson(const JSON: String)`.

In such a case you could use the version of `FromJson` method that takes `ISuperObject` as an argument that has date recognition explicitly disabled:

```
var LSuperObject: ISuperObject := TSuperObject.Create(Resp.Data[i], {CheckDate}False);
var Item := TSuperRecord<TMySelectedItem>.FromJSON(LSuperObject);
```

But this won't work either due to bugs in the library:

1. The value of `CheckDate` parameter is not propagated to nested objects. Method [`TBaseJSON<T, Typ>.GetObject(V: Typ): ISuperObject`](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject/blob/2d3ec012e6e55677bb054b95977db290a185844e/XSuperObject.pas#L1007) returns new instance of `TSuperObject` with `CheckDate` enabled by default.
2. Unmarshalling values of type `ISuperObject` inside `TSuperRecord<T>.FromJSON()` also ignores the value of `CheckDate` parameter that was used to create `TSuperObject` instance. See method [`TSuperObject.Clone: ISuperObject`](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject/blob/2d3ec012e6e55677bb054b95977db290a185844e/XSuperObject.pas#L1211C5-L1211C5)

Those are just two bugs that apply to your scenario, but I guess there's more, because the library lacks test suite. In theory you could ask the author to fix those bugs, or contribute bug fixes, but based on [issues](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject/issues) and [commits](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject/commits/master) the project seems pretty much dead to me.

The library contains static class `TJSONDateManager` that is responsible for recognizing dates. It contains `Formats` class property which is initialized with ISO-8601 format. Clearing these formats will disable any date recognition and the solution to your specific problem will become one-liner:

```
TJSONDateManager.Formats.Clear;
```

At this point you depend on the library that is buggy and you probably won't get any support. I strongly recommend you to switch to some other library.

FWIW, the proposed fixes to bugs mentioned above are:

```
function TBaseJSON<T, Typ>.GetObject(V: Typ): ISuperObject;
begin
  Result := Nil;
  if not Member(V) then
    Member<TJSONObject, Pointer>(V, Nil);

  //Original: Result := TSuperObject.Create(GetValue<TJSONObject>(V));
  Result := TSuperObject.Create(GetValue<TJSONObject>(V), FCheckDate);
end;

function TSuperObject.Clone: ISuperObject;
begin
  //Original: Result := SO(AsJSON);
  Result := TSuperObject.Create(AsJSON, FCheckDate);
end;
```